# Should I switch to Windows 7 for primary development?

Tags: windows-7, development-environment

Is it time to switch to Win7 for primary dev? I mostly deal with maven, eclipse, eclipse-derivatives, VMWare workstation, virtualbox, and other dev-centric tools. I'm wary to switch now, but I have msdn access to the RTM release, and I'm thinking of upgrading? What are your concerns for Windows 7? Have you switched yet? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Have been using it since Beta and had zero problems with VS, Eclipse, SQL Server, VMware.

Comment: same here. runs really good. would never go back to vista or xp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're developing in Vista, yes.  If you're still using XP, stick with that until at least the first few months pass and they work out most of the potentially major unidentified issues with 7 (There's always some hidden surprises the first few months after a major OS release).

Comment: I agree. If you're already using Vista it can't hurt anything to upgrade. I've been really happy with 7.

Comment: I'm using XP. The target platforms aren't really an issue, as I target linux, mac, and windows XP/Vista/2000/7, so I'm forced to use virtual machines regularly :P. Virtualization saves my life, and virtualbox rocks. Needs darwin support, but other than that...

Answer (score 3):

I have switched, and I would recommend it. Like everyone else points out I am sure there will be a few gotchas but I have been running 1st on the RC and now on The RTM and haven't hit one yet. With the increases in performance over vista, security over XP, and usability over any previous windows OS I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it depends on two factors:

- Are there tools that you need that are only available in Windows 7, or whose performance is improved in Windows 7?  Your answer to this may depend on whether you're currently in XP or Vista.
- How quickly do you expect your customer base to switch to Windows 7 and away from other Windows versions?

Unless you can make a good business case for the switch, I'd wait.

Comment: No tools are Win7 only. I do like that Win7 has the XP emu, though. I thought that was a strong move.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using Win7 since beta and have had no issues with eclipse or vmware. You may want to try it on vmware with the programs you are using to make sure you don't experience any other issues but so far my experience has been excellent

Answer (score 1):

Win7 is mostly Vista with significant kernel upgrade; driver base is the same, as are other major parts...

So the answer depends on what you were using until now ...

Comment: Windows 7 does not have an upgraded kernel from Vista: http://www.osnews.com/story/19793/No_New_Kernel_Builds_on_Vista

Comment: Also see here: http://www.pcworld.com/article/153624/under_the_hood_windows_7_is_vistas_twin.html